# Using Payoneer accounts in Fiverr's disabled account

Tags: freelance-websites

Can we use a Payoneer account for a fiverr account when it is already attached to a disabled fiverr account?

Answer (score 1):

You can never use two Payoneer cards with one Fiverr account. Similarly, two Fiverr accounts can never be attached to single Payoneer account.